# How to receive the MethodChannel.Result on Android side (Kotlin)?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, flutter-method-channel

I want to call Flutter method and get returned data from android side.
I use MethodChannel and want to get the data returned by Flutter (override fun success).

This is the function to call Flutter method.

```
fun callFlutterMethod(flutterMethod: String, params: Map<String, String>): String? {
    var res: String? = null
    val deferred = CompletableDeferred<String>()
    var job = CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
        channel!!.invokeMethod(flutterMethod, params, object : MethodChannel.Result {

            override fun success(result: Any?) {
                println("MethodChannel.Result， success: $result")
                deferred.complete(result.toString())

            }

            override fun error(errorCode: String, errorMessage: String?, errorDetails: Any?) {
                println("callFlutterMethod error: $errorCode, $errorMessage,$errorDetails")

            }

            override fun notImplemented() {
                println("callFlutterMethod error: notImplemented")

            }
        })

    }
    runBlocking {
        launch {
            res=deferred.await()
        }
    }


    println("Android received result: $res")

    return res
}
```

---

08:44:05.926  W  dispatcher 0x730b26c380 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x736f6674
08:44:08.930  W  dispatcher 0x730b26c380 ~ ignoring unknown event type 0x736f6674
08:44:11.823  E  START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10600000 hwFlg=0x10 cmp=com.wordx.robot_one/com.wordx.ro_plugin.MainActivity bnds=[649,1604][857,1885] (has extras)} result: 2

---

The problem is that I can't block Main/UiThread, or it will stopping the process to receive Flutter return.
How to solve it? I am a newbie.

- runBlocking: not  work
- suspendCoroutine: not  work
- async: not  work

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple function to do add some number into the list of number

**In flutter side code is:**

```
  MethodChannel channel = const MethodChannel('testMethodChannel');

  void _getSumOfNumbers() async {
      num sum = await channel.invokeMethod('sumNumbers', {
        'numbers': [5, 6.5, 5]
      });
      print('sum value is: $sum'); //11.5
    }
```

**In android side code**

```
  class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
      private var channelName = "testMethodChannel"
      private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

      override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
          super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

          val channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, channelName)

          channel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
              when (call.method) {
                  "sumNumbers" -> {
                      val arguments = call.arguments as HashMap<String, Any>;
                      val numList = arguments["numbers"] as List<Double>
                      val sum = numList.sum()
                      result.success(sum)
                  }
                  else -> {
                      print("nothing to do on method channel")
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is calling Flutter from Android side. You are call Andrioid from Flutter.

Comment: you need to pass data from flutter

Comment: The problem is that I can't get the value returned by Flutter.  I want to find some way to await the returned data in override success(){}. Then I will pass the data  to some other palces.

Comment: The problem is that I can't get the value returned by Flutter.